# How to set up an ethernet and wireless network using /etc/network/interfaces?

Tags: networking, configuration, network-manager

Currently I have ethernet and wireless networks configured through a network manager (further NM) but it seems to be a bit buggy (I need a different MAC for ether which is never applied if using NM), so I would like to move all the network configs to interfaces file. I know (or can google for) configuration code, but I'm not sure how NM works and it looks like it overrides interface config. Please advice, how I can handle this issue.

**NOTE**: I also would like to be able to locate and connect to various wireless networks but not sure how to do it.

Comment: Have you considered using the nmcli command-line tool?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set `managed=false` in `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` to remove network interfaces control to interfaces file.

Command to stop network manager:

```
/etc/init.d/network-manager stop
```

For detailed documentation, please refer to:

- http://wiki.debian.org/NetworkManager, section #Wired Networks are Unmanaged

And for WiFi management please refer to:

- http://wiki.debian.org/WiFi/HowToUse#SwitchingConnections

Answer (score 0):

This will help you bypass network manager's control completely.

`sudoedit /etc/network/interfaces` or `sudo gedit /etc/network/interfaces`

Replace `gedit` with your preferred text editor. Make sure that eth0, or whichever your networking interface is, is not commented out. Remove the `#` before it. As long as the interface is listed in this file, it won't matter if you've NM installed or not.

Comment: For a graphical text editor like Gedit, `gksu` (or `gksudo`) should be used instead of straight `sudo`, [to avoid breaking things](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo#Graphical_sudo).